# permanent redirect of url's with .html and w/o .html

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, http-status-code-301

I am doing some permanent url redirects through .htaccess

I am using the following code:

```
Redirect permanent /someurl.html http://thedomain.com/newurl.html
```

I would like the redirect to apply to url s that end with .html and that end with non .html

example

```
Redirect permanent /someurl.html http://thedomain.com/newurl.html
Redirect permanent /someurl http://thedomain.com/newurl.html
```

How could achieve this without the two lines (is there a way to abbreviate)?

Thank you,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if you can use regexs in `Redirect` statements but if you can this should work:

```
Redirect permanent /someurl(.html)? http://thedomain.com/newurl$1
```

If you can't, a RewriteRule like this should work instead:

```
RewriteRule ^someurl(.html)?$ http://thedomain.com/newurl$1 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: No, you can't. You must use RedirectMatch instead.

Comment: @Clive, this worked for me RewriteRule ^someurl(.html)?$ http://thedomain.com/newurl$1 [L,R=301] THANK YOU

Comment: @tcurvelo could you write an example? Thank you

Answer (score 2):

You can use [RedirectMatch directive](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_alias.html#redirectmatch) instead. It is equivalent to Redirect, but makes use of regular expressions.

Your rule would look like this:

```
RedirectMatch permanent someurl($|\.html) http://thedomain.com/newurl.html
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: uh quickfingers...  tried: RedirectMatch permanent (someurl)($|\.html) http://thedomain.com/$1.html DID NOT WORKED  I tried RedirectMatch permanent someurl($|\.html) http://thedomain.com/otherUrl.html THIS WORKS !!! thank you

Answer (score 1):

or you can just redirect by folder

```
Redirect permanent /one http://example.com/two
```

Like so

Read doc/manual here.
http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_alias.html#redirect

Comment: Sorry, I made a mistake... this does not work. If url is set as http://thedomain.com/one : When I http://thedomain.com/one.html I get a 404 rather than http://thedomain.com/two or http://thedomain.com/two.html